# CSS keeping divs on top of one another

Tags: html, css, web

I'm pretty bad at CSS and don't know what I'm doing. I've made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kvpaa3se/).

Here is the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Prilyx Test">
        <meta name="author" content="Prilyx">
        <!-- Mobile Specific Metas -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- Font -->

        <!-- CSS -->
        <!-- JS -->
        <script src="js/test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        var employees = [ { id:1, user: '[Name Here]'} ];
        </script>
        <div id="main" class="main bg-grey overflow-scroll-both">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript file:

```
/*======================================================
Global variables
======================================================*/
var m_bInitialized = false;
var m_bFirstLoad = true;

var node_id = 0;

/**
Key Presses
*/
var keyShiftPressed = false;
var keyCtrlPressed = false;

/**
Elements
*/
var elementMain;
var employees = [{
    id: 1,
    user: '[Name Here]'
}];

/*======================================================
Initialization functions
======================================================*/
window.onload = function() {
    console.log("Test");

    elementMain = document.getElementById("main");

    init();
}

/**
The main initialization function that gets called once the body
of the webpage has loaded.
**/
var init = function() {
    var node = {
        id: "0",
        body: "Test",
        creator_id: "1",
        created_at: "2016-07-21 00:00:00"
    };
    addNodes(node);
}

/**
Things to load after the page has initialized
**/
var load = function() {

}



/*======================================================
Clean up functions
======================================================*/
window.onbeforeunload = function() {

}

/*======================================================
Helper functions specific to this page
======================================================*/
Number.prototype.pad = function(size) {
    var s = String(this);
    while (s.length < (size || 2)) {
        s = "0" + s;
    }
    return s;
}

function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode,referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

var addNodes = function(node) {
    console.log("adding node");
    var ele = document.createElement("div");
    ele.style.display = "inline-block";
    ele.style.minWith = "450px";
    ele.style.whiteSpace = "normal";
    ele.style.borderRadius = "4px";
    ele.style.margin = "5px";
    ele.style.verticalAlign = "top";
    ele.style.backgroundColor = "#d05656";

    var header = document.createElement("header");
    header.innerHTML = "Default";
    header.style.color = "white";
    header.style.textShadow = "0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
    header.style.fontSize = "1.6em";
    header.style.textAlign = "center";
    header.style.marginTop = "15px";
    for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
        if (employees[i]['id'] == node['creator_id']) {
            ele.id = 'e_' + employees[i]['id'];
            header.innerHTML = employees[i]['user'];
            break;
        }
    }
    ele.appendChild(header);

    var times = document.createElement("div");
    times.style.width = "auto";
    times.style.height = "auto";

    for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {

        var timenode = document.createElement("div");
        timenode.style.width = "450px";
        timenode.style.height = "auto";
        timenode.style.marginBottom = "20px";
        timenode.style.marginLeft = "10px";
        timenode.style.marginRight = "10px";
        timenode.style.marginBottom = "10px";
        timenode.style.paddingBottom = "2px";
        if (i < 23) {
            timenode.style.marginTop = "5px";
        }
        times.appendChild(timenode);

        var timestamp = document.createElement("i");
        timestamp.style.marginLeft = "10px";
        timestamp.style.marginTop = "10px";
        timestamp.style.backgroundColor = "#D8B279";
        timestamp.style.color = "white";
        timestamp.style.textShadow = "0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
        timestamp.style.fontSize = "1em";
        var time = "2016-07-21 " + (i).pad() + ":00:00";
        timestamp.innerHTML = time;
        timenode.appendChild(timestamp);

        var nodeList = document.createElement("div");
        nodeList.style.width = "auto";
        nodeList.style.minWidth = "150px";
        nodeList.style.minHeight = "100px";
        nodeList.style.height = "auto";

        timenode.appendChild(nodeList);

        var end = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
        for (var j = 0; j < end; j++) {
            var node = document.createElement("textarea");
            node.id = node_id++;
            node.style.float = "none";
            node.style.clear = "both";
            node.style.width = "150px";
            node.style.height = "100px";
            node.style.display = "inline-block";
            node.style.verticalAlign = "top";
            node.style.marginTop = "5px";
            node.style.marginBottom = "5px";
            node.style.marginLeft = "10px";
            node.style.marginRight = "10px";
            node.style.border = "none";
            node.style.resize = "none";
            node.style.backgroundColor = "#39853e";
            node.style.textAlign = "center";
            node.style.color = "white";
            node.style.textShadow = "0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
            node.style.fontSize = "1.4em";

            node.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {

                } else if (e.keyCode == 16) {
                    keyShiftPressed = true;
                    return;
                } else if (e.keyCode == 17) {
                    keyCtrlPressed = true;
                    return;
                } else {
                    return;
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            node.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
                console.log(e.keyCode);
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    if (keyShiftPressed && !keyCtrlPressed) {
                        addNode(this, true, false);
                    } else if (!keyShiftPressed && keyCtrlPressed) {
                        addNode(this, false, true);
                    } else {
                        addNode(this, false, false);
                    }
                } else if (e.keyCode == 16) {
                    keyShiftPressed = false;
                    return;
                } else if (e.keyCode == 17) {
                    keyCtrlPressed = false;
                    return;
                } else {
                    return;
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            nodeList.appendChild(node);
        }

    }
    ele.appendChild(times);

    main.appendChild(ele);
}


var addNode = function(self, subtask, previoustask) {
    var node = document.createElement("textarea");
    node.id = node_id++;
    node.style.float = "none";
    node.style.clear = "both";
    node.style.width = "150px";
    node.style.height = "100px";
    node.style.display = "inline-block";
    node.style.verticalAlign = "middle";
    node.style.marginTop = "5px";
    node.style.marginBottom = "5px";
    if (!subtask && !previoustask) {
        node.style.marginLeft = self.style.marginLeft;
    } else if (subtask && !previoustask) {
        node.style.marginLeft = parseInt(self.style.marginLeft.slice(0, -2)) + 120 + "px";
    } else if (!subtask && previoustask) {
        if (parseInt(node.style.marginLeft.slice(0, -2)) < 100) {
            node.style.marginLeft = self.style.marginLeft;
        } else {
            node.style.marginLeft = parseInt(self.style.marginLeft.slice(0, -2)) - 120 + "px";
        }
    }
    node.style.marginRight = "10px";
    node.style.border = "none";
    node.style.resize = "none";
    node.style.backgroundColor = "#39853e";
    node.style.textAlign = "center";
    node.style.color = "white";
    node.style.textShadow = "0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
    node.style.fontSize = "1.4em";

    node.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {

        } else if (e.keyCode == 16) {
            keyShiftPressed = true;
        } else if (e.keyCode == 17) {
            keyCtrlPressed = true;
            return;
        } else {
            return;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    node.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
        console.log(e.keyCode);
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            if (keyShiftPressed && !keyCtrlPressed) {
                addNode(this, true, false);
            } else if (!keyShiftPressed && keyCtrlPressed) {
                addNode(this, false, true);
            } else {
                addNode(this, false, false);
            }
        } else if (e.keyCode == 16) {
            keyShiftPressed = false;
        } else if (e.keyCode == 17) {
            keyCtrlPressed = false;
            return;
        } else {
            return;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    insertAfter(node, self);

    node.focus();
}
```

What I'm trying to do is, make those green nodes stack on top of each other instead of to the right. When someone presses enter, a green node is placed directly underneath the current node. If shift+enter is pressed, a node is placed underneath but pushed forward a margin of a nodes width. If ctrl+enter is pressed, a node is placed underneath but pulled back, up until it is at the left-most.

Like this:
[Example design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExmNi.png)

Comment: What you are actually saying: I have no clue about CSS, can you do it for me? That is not going to happen on SO.

Comment: I'm not asking for someone to do it for me, in the fiddle it is almost done. All my nodes are being put to the right of each other instead of stacking on top of each other. I've tried floating them but the entire thing just breaks, I tried wrapping them but it breaks, I'm not very good at CSS and was asking for help getting them to stack

Comment: Ok, I do humbly appologize. And cudos for solving it, seriously!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it myself, I was able to get the divs to stack on top of each other.

html

```
<div class="employees">
        <div class="employee">
            <header>[Name]</header>
            <div class="nodes">
                <div class="node">
                    <div class="timestamps">
                        <div class="width-full text-white text-outline">2016-07-22 08:00:00</div>
                    </div>
                    <textarea class="node-text text-white text-outline"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="node" style="margin-left: 220px;">
                </div>
                <div class="node" style="margin-left: 430px;">
                </div>
                <div class="node" style="margin-left: 430px;">
                </div>
                <div class="node" style="margin-left: 220px;">
                </div>
                <div class="node">
                </div>
                <div class="node">
                </div>
                <div class="node" style="margin-left: 220px;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="employee">
            <header>[Name]</header>
            <div class="nodes">
                <div class="node">
                </div>
                <div class="node">
                </div>
                <div class="node">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="employee">
            <header>[Name]</header>
            <div class="nodes">
                <div class="node">
                </div>
                <div class="node">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="employee">
            <header>[Name]</header>
            <div class="nodes">
                <div class="node">
                </div>
                <div class="node">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.employees
{
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.employee 
{
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: normal;
    background-color: #ff8888;
    max-width: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 10px 10px;
}

.employee header
{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 1px black;
    padding: 10px 0px;
}

.overflow-scroll-x
{
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.overflow-scroll-y
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.overflow-scroll-both
{
    overflow: scroll;
}

.overflow-hidden-x
{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.overflow-hidden-y
{
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.overflow-hidden-both
{
    overflow: hidden;
}

.width-full
{
    width: 100%;
}

.height-full
{
    height: 100vh;
}

.border-none
{
    border: 0;
}

.nodes
{
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.node
{
    float: top;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #568C54;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.node-text
{
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
    height: calc(100% - 30px);
    border: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    resize: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 30px 5px 0px 5px;
}

.timestamps
{
    background-color: #fff3b2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 140px;
}

.text-outline
{
    text-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 1px black;
}

.text-outline-inverse
{
    text-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 1px white;
}

.text-white
{
    color: white;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8oa7paw/5/)